# Spring Data JPA custom count query not showing all records

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The query is not returning all the records, i.e all the records whose count is same out of them only of is being returned.
Where as the same code of MYSQL workbench works like a charm

JPA Custom Query

```
public interface BookingRepository extends JpaRepository<Booking, Long> {

    @Query("select count(v.source), concat(v.source,'-', v.destination) as bus_route from Booking v group by v.source, v.destination")
    public List<Object[]> groupByBus();
}
```

[image: Output]

Query in MYSQL

```
SELECT count(source), concat(source," - ", destination) as bus_route
FROM booking
GROUP BY source, destination;
```

[image]

As you can see there are two records with count of one, but only one is being returned by Spring data jpa

Comment: Just change the return type from `List<Object[]>` to `List<Map<String, Object>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query return a `List<Object[]>` but the object array could be almost everything.

Actually, `Object[]` contains, for each position, another `Object[]` with two values: `count` and `bus_route`.

You can iterate over every value in this way (I've tested and I've needed `BigInteger` to cast the object value):

```java
Map<BigInteger,String> map = new HashMap<BigInteger,String>();
for(Object object[] : objectList) map.put((BigInteger)object[0], (String)object[1]);
```

And you will get the map you want.

Also, if there could be repeated values, only create a new list instead of `Map`.